# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException trhown when calling signal()

Tags: java, multithreading

i' m working in a multithreading program. The threads are working in a matrix (workerThread) and i have got a thread (display) that print the matrix state.i' m getting this exception, ***inside the increaseRow() of Matrix class at the line monitor.signal()***

can someone tell me, what's wrong?

```
public class Matrix {

    private int row;
    private int column;

    private int[][] matrix;
    private Map<Integer, String> mapForRow;
    private Map<Integer, String> mapForColumn;

    private Lock lock;
    private Condition condition;
    private Condition monitor;

    private boolean rowIncreased;
    private boolean columnIncreased;
    private boolean columnCanBeAdded;
    private boolean rowCanBeAdded;
    private boolean print;

    public Matrix(int row, int column) {
        this.matrix = new int[row][column];
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        mapForColumn = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        mapForRow = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        condition = lock.newCondition();
        monitor = lock.newCondition();
        rowIncreased = false;
        columnIncreased = false;
        rowCanBeAdded = false;
        columnCanBeAdded = false;
        print = false;
    }

    public void increaseRow(int row) {
        if (!mapForRow.containsKey(row))
            mapForRow.put(row, "not increased");
        if (mapForRow.get(row).equals("not increased") && !columnIncreased) {
            mapForRow.get(row).equals("increased");
            rowIncreased = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                setMatrix(row, j, matrix[row][j] + 1);
            mapForRow.put(row, "not increased");
            rowIncreased = false;
            print = true;
            monitor.signal();
        }
    }

    public void increaseColumn(int column) {
        if (!mapForColumn.containsKey(column))
            mapForColumn.put(column, "not increased");
        if (mapForColumn.get(column).equals("not increased") && !rowIncreased) {
            mapForColumn.get(column).equals("increased");
            columnIncreased = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
                setMatrix(i, column, matrix[i][column] + 1);
            mapForColumn.put(column, "not increased");
            columnIncreased = false;
            print = true;
            monitor.signal();
        }
    }

    public int sumColumn(int column) {
        lock.lock();
        int sum = 0;
        try {
            columnCanBeAdded = false;
            while (columnIncreased || rowIncreased || rowCanBeAdded) {
                condition.await();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
                sum += matrix[i][column];
            columnCanBeAdded = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        condition.signalAll();
        print = true;
        monitor.signal();
        return sum;
    }

    public int sumRow(int row) {
        lock.lock();
        int sum = 0;
        try {
            rowCanBeAdded = false;
            while (columnIncreased || rowIncreased || columnCanBeAdded) {
                condition.await();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                sum += matrix[row][j];
            rowCanBeAdded = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        condition.signalAll();
        print = true;
        monitor.signal();
        return sum;
    }

    public void printMatrix() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!print) {
                monitor.await();
            }
            System.out.println("begin print matrix");
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("end print matrix");
            print = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    public void setMatrix(int row, int column, int number) {
        matrix[row][column] = number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(10, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                matrix.setMatrix(i, j, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(matrix);
            workerThread.start();
        }
        // print the matrix state
        Display display = new Display(matrix);
        display.start();

    }
}
```

the display class:

```
    public class Display extends Thread {

        private Matrix matrix;

        public Display(Matrix matrix) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            matrix.printMatrix();
        }

    }
```

the workerThread class:

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    private Matrix matrix;

    public WorkerThread(Matrix matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // prevent thread to die
        while (true) {
            matrix.increaseColumn(new Random().nextInt(9));
            matrix.increaseRow(new Random().nextInt(9));
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            matrix.sumRow(new Random().nextInt(9));
            matrix.sumColumn(new Random().nextInt(9));
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" Exception in thread "Thread-6" Exception in thread "Thread-4" Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception in thread "Thread-9" Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-2" Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1941)
    at Matrix.increaseColumn(Matrix.java:67)
    at WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:15)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1941)
    at Matrix.increaseColumn(Matrix.java:67)
    at WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:15)begin print matrix
end print matrix
```

Comment: Can you also include a stack trace of the generated exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that in `increaseRow` you're calling `monitor.signal()` without having locked `lock` first. From the documentation for [`Condition.signal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--):

> An implementation may (and typically does) require that the current thread hold the lock associated with this Condition when this method is called. Implementations must document this precondition and any actions taken if the lock is not held. Typically, an exception such as `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.

Both your `increaseRow` and `increaseColumn` methods should have a structure of

```
lock.lock();
try {
    // code including monitor.signal() here
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

just as your `sumRow`, `sumColumn` and `printMatrix` methods do. Alternatively, you may want to have a separate monitor (and conditions) for each row and for each column. You basically need to consider all your concurrency constraints - it's hard to give more guidance without more idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, for the answer, in the method `increaseRow` , i don't have to lock, because more thread can enter, in differents rows.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Well you *do* have to lock if you're going to call `monitor.signal()`.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: You might want to consider having one lock per row. That way you can properly handle concurrent requests for the same row, without blocking concurrent requests for *different* rows.

Comment: my problem is: all operations inside the matrix must be `thread-safe`. my operations are: **increase +1 a selected row, increase +1 a selected column and sum a selected row, and sum a selected column** So for example: i can increase +1  different columns or different rows but i must be careful on sum all numbers inside a row or sum all number inside a column. (`look at my program as i tried to write this`)

Comment: with increase +1 i mean the numbers, and naturally i can't increase a row while i'm increasing a column.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Right. Basically I think you've got a naturally difficult problem here - especially if you're going to require two locks per cell (one per column, one per row) and lock both of them.

Comment: can i insert two different locks, one for row and one for column ?.

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku: Potentially. But then you need to consider that if you're changing all the values in a column, you're changing values in multiple rows...

Comment: yes, is much problematic to control, but it can avoid deadlock and is more parallel.

Answer (score 4):

In methods `increaseRow(int)` and `increaseColumn(int)` you need to have a lock held on `lock`, otherwise you cannot call the `monitor.signal()`

```
lock.lock();
try {
     ....
     monitor.signal();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

From the docs for [signal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--)

> An implementation may (and typically does) require that the current thread hold the lock associated with this Condition when this method is called.

and then for [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#newCondition--):

> If this lock is not held when any of the Condition waiting or signalling methods are called, then an IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

Comment: thanks, for the answer, in the method increaseRow , i don't have to lock, because more thread can enter, in differents rows